# How to check keyboard input special character "#" like hashtag by Swift

Tags: ios, swift, textview, uitextview

I want to do the hashtag in my UITextView, and I check the text whether contain "#" or not.
If the user inputs "#" ,I'll show the list of keywords to let user click.
 
Then the user inputs second hastag like "#yummy #", I also show the list of keywords.
How to check the user input "#", and trigger to show the list of keywords.
Thanks.

Image like following Pic.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Swift 4.0**

To perform action on # character you can use delegate method to detect if user enter # character as like below

1) Assign delegate to `UITextView`

```
textView.delegate = self
```

2) Implement below method of delegate.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if text == "#" {
            //Perform here some task when user enters # character
        }
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the protocol `UITextViewDelegate`, and a function `textView(_:shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String)` in that protocol to be specific.

The parameter `replacementString` provides you the currently entered string which you can test for the equality with the required string and proceed accordingly. For more details please read [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618630-textview).